# Equicontinuity of a set of periodic functions

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having a little trouble understanding when the family of functions $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by 
$$f_n(x) = \cos(n+x) + \log(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\sin^2(n^nx))$$ is equicontinuous.

My progress so far:

As $n \to \infty$, we know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}} \to 0$, and that $\sin^2(n^nx)$ forever oscillates between 0 and 1, implying that the entire $\log$ portion of the above function goes to $0$ for large $n$. The problem so reduces to checking if the family of functions given by $$f_n(x) = \cos(n + x)$$ is equicontinuous for large $n$.

Uniform equicontinuity states that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that for all $s, t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have 
$$|s - t| < \delta \implies |f_n(s) - f_n(t)| < \epsilon$$
At any given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a function $f_k$ in the set such that $f_k(x) > f_n(x)$ for all other functions in the set. Hence, it seems that we can pick a value of $\epsilon$ such that the equicontinuity condition holds for all functions save $f_k$, say by setting $\epsilon = |f_{k-1}(s) - f_{k-1}(t)|$. Hence, the functions are not uniformly equicontinuous.

However this goes against my intuition of equicontinuity as describing a family of functions as being 'equally continuous'. What exactly am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for all positive $\delta$ and all integer $n$, 
$$
\sup_{\substack{x,y\in\mathbb R\\ \left\lvert x-y\right\rvert\lt\delta}}\left\lvert \cos\left(n+x\right)-\cos\left(n+y\right)\right\rvert=
\sup_{\substack{x',y'\in\mathbb R\\ \left\lvert x'-y'\right\rvert\lt\delta}}\left\lvert \cos\left(x'\right)-\cos\left(y'\right)\right\rvert$$
hence equicontinuity reduces to uniform continuity on $\mathbb R$ of $t\mapsto \cos\left(t\right)$.